# Screen freeze while loading UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios9.3

I am Loading HTML String in `UIWebView`,text content get loaded in a sec but there is lot of images in `HTML` String, cause of this image my `UIWebView` get freeze, after loaded all images my screen get free to use.

Any Suggestion on this?

Comment: Have you implemented delegate of uiwebview? Can you show your code?

Comment: yes i implemented delegates, but i think the problems in the images, after load all images my uiwebview gets free.

Comment: Is your `webview` has full screen size?

Comment: NO, actually after loaded UIWebview i resize the height of UIWebview.

Answer (score 1):

Load webview in dispatch thread, try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"htmlstring" baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's freezing because you're loading a images from web in your main thread, Which is also responsible for redrawing your UI. By loading a large images inside your thread, your UI freezes as well.

I would recommend moving the code that does images loading into a separate thread.
(you can use @Andey's answer)

Comment: I tried andey's solution but still getting issue, the problems is in the images because if i disconnect the net then string get loaded into UIWebview and screen not get freeze.

Comment: you're loading a images from web in your main thread.try to do into a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Andey said, you should dispatch off the main queue whenever the thing you're doing will take some time and you don't want your view to freeze.

Try lecture 9:
https://itunes.apple.com/en/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099

---

**UPDATE** (*Swift* ver.):

Although I do not know how to write this in *Obj-C*, it will look something like this in *Swift*, which you can later translate it back to *Obj-c*.

```
dispatch_async(notTheMainQueue) {
    // Some time consuming stuff you're doing (downloading data, calculating..)
    ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) {
        // Set your view here, which dispatches *back* to the main queue and will not block your UI
        ...
    }
}
```